# How should I do to wait for this stream to complete before res.send is called?

Tags: node.js, express, stream, sparql, httpresponse

I'm trying to do a request to this route and execute this sparql query. How should I do to wait for this stream.on() to finish and then call res.send()? I get the data inside stream.on().
I'm using sparql-http-client library to send the query to the rdf4j server and express.js to create this route.

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  
  let endpointUrl = "http://localhost:8080/rdf4j-server/repositories/graph";
  let regions = [];
  const query = `
  PREFIX : <http://abc.ro#>
  PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
  PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
  SELECT ?name
  WHERE 
  {
      ?region a schema:DefinedRegion.
      ?region rdfs:label ?name
  }`;
  
  const client = new sparql({ endpointUrl });
  const stream = await client.query.select(query);

  stream.on('data', row => {
    regions.push(row.name.value);   
  });
  
  stream.on('error', err => {
    console.error(err)
  });
  
  res.send(regions); // this is sending an empty array
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check the `enter code here`'end' event on a readable stream.

```
  stream.on('end', err => {
     res.send(regions);
  });
```

Comment: If this answer works, you can accept it so that user coming to this thread can use it as accepted user.